# Couchbase TTL for buckets

Tags: java, spring-data, couchbase

Can TTL be set for couchbase buckets or can it only be set for each document persisted within the bucket.I am using couchbase java sdk for creating documents within CB

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot configure server to assign or override TTL for all documents

Read more about TTL: http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/core-operations.html#devguide_kvcore_generic__expiry

but you can extend `JsonDocument` class and override default TTL in there.

Comment: Thanks @avsej. I'll go over the link. So will the documented be deleted from persistent store after ttl expiry?

Comment: It will not be accessible after expiration, but it doesn't mean that server remove documents precisely at expiration time

Comment: Once the object expires, Couchbase marks the object as expired (now the object is inaccessible by normal means) and there is a background job that will actually do the delete. It also creates a tombstone. This is needed for the purposes of inter and intra cluster replication.